Google Firestore - how to send data to the frontend?
If I make a call from Node to Firestore like this:
const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const firebaseDb = getFirestore(firebaseApp);
const documents = collection(firebaseDb, 'documents');

const notesQuery = query(documents, where('noteType', '==', 'private'));
const notesDocs = await getDocs(notesQuery);

I am successfully connecting to the DB and I successfully get a response. How do I send all of the docs to the frontend?
The Firebase documentation uses a foreEach() to loop through the docs that are returned. But is it possible to send the response to the frontend without looping through first?
I'm using Koa, so I want to do something like this to send the data to the frontend:
ctx.status = 200;
ctx.body = { data: notesDocs };

Would it be required to loop through all of the returned docs to prepare my data before sending it?
UPDATE AFTER INITIAL POST:
More Context:
On the frontend, I am using React and I am fetching data like this:
fetch('/api/notes')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log('---DATA', data)})
  .catch(error => console.error(error)

In my initial post I was confused because I console logged notesDocs and I saw a huge object in my server console. That seemed like a lot of extra unnecessary data to pass to the frontend. Every source I've found online about this, uses a forEach() to solve it, but I think that would become an expensive task for the server, at scale. What if there are 1000 notes frequently retrieved by 100+ users? It seems like it would be more efficient to offload the iteration task to the client side. So now I am trying to figure out how to do that.
At the time of my initial post, I had tried ctx.body = notesDocs but that wasn't the JSON data for the documents. It was the same large object that I saw in the server console. I'm trying to get the JSON data for the documents.
Since my initial post I have made a little progress. I replaced ctx.body = { data: notesDocs } with ctx.body = noteDocs.docs and I think that got me going in the right direction. However, now I am still in a similar situation. I can't figure out how to retrieve the data. I get an array of docs looks like this:


On the frontend I have tried the following:
const notes = data.map(item => item.data())
const notes = data.map(item => item.get())
const notes = data.map(item => item.document())
const notes = data.map(item => item.document.data())
const notes = data.map(item => item.document.data.value())
const notes = data.map(item => item.document)

All of those produce an error similar to:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')


I'm having a hard time understanding the problem here. Can't you just return nodesDocs? If not, why not? And please don't explain in a comment, but edit your question to show the context of this code and what isn't working with the approach you tried.

@puf-FrankvanPuffelen updated

"Every source I've found online about this, uses a forEach() to solve it, but I think that would become an expensive task for the server, at scale" I don't think iterating over 1,000 documents is gonna take significant time, especially not when you compare it to the effort of transferring the data for those same documents to the clients. I could be wrong about that of course, but this sounds like a case of premature optimization.

Perhaps. But if I remember right, other services like Azure's Cosmos and MongoDB Atlas just send the JSON and then I relay that to the frontend where I then iterate over it. It seems odd to me that Firestore wants us to do that on the server. Is it possible to achieve what I'm trying to do? I feel like I'm close.

If you want to access Firestore on the client, you should use its client-side SDKs. If you want to access it on the server, use its server-side SDKs (as you do) - but at that point transferring the data back to the client becomes your responsibility. --- Note though thats the bigger deal is that you're optimizing prematurely: a loop like the one you point out costs very little time compared to the network cost. If you think that's not the case, the best way to show that is to test and measure the performance and share that code and data.

To transfer Firestore data back from a server-side endpoint to a client, all I typically return is the ID and the data of each document. A common snippet for this return querySnapshot.map((doc) => { doc.id, ...doc.data() }).
